# How to install matplotlib on Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation

I have the [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) for windows installer. I'm trying to install [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) on it. From this [page](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements) it says I need to download the dependencies first using

`sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`

But when I do that I get this

```
me@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python-matplotlib'
E: Unable to find a source package for matplotlib
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable  Universe repository in software and updates and then run the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Comment: How do I `Enable Universe repository in software and updates`?

Comment: open software and updates from dash.Then enable the community maintained free and open source softwares(universe) repository.

Comment: When I type software, I only get `Ubuntu Software Center` and when that opens I see no option to enable the universe repo.

Comment: try this `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

Comment: ok that ran fine